# When is it worth defining a new data type

Tags: c++

Bjarne Stroustrup recommends using types which reflect real concepts (units etc.) in preference to using primitives.  For example [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style), he recommends using a type "Point" instead of two integers.

The benefits of this kind of approach are clear. It means the compiler can ensure parameters are of the same conceptual type, not just the same representation in memory.  One example Stroustrup gives is ensuring physical values are in the same units.

My problem is how to do this in practice.  It's not difficult to create a new class of type `Point`, or so on, but then I include a 3rd party library which has it's own `Point` object, which of course can't be constructed from one of mine.  If I include a second library, and then a 3rd, the problem multiplies.

What approaches do people take to this problem in practice?  Is there an elegant solution?

Comment: Sounds like a job for namespaces!

Comment: If you use a library which already have a `Point` class, why not simply use *that* class instead of making your own?

Comment: Let me clarify, my problem isn't how to stop the names conflicting, I'm more wondering how people manage multiple types for the same concept.  Should my function accept a InHousePoint and convert it to a 3rdPartyPoint if that's what it needs internally? Should I just try and use 3rdPartyPoint everywhere?

Comment: How about namespaces?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, that's probably a good approach, my concern was that I would introduce a dependency on that library for pieces of my code which don't really need it.

Comment: You might want to use a facade pattern (GoF), or decorator, as a way of making your libraries more palatable.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to try is of course to try and use the functionality of the libraries you use, instead of making your own.

If that's not possible, and you want compatibility with the similar classes in the library, you can make constructors and assignment operators that takes the class from the library, and use the data from that in constructing your own objects.

Something like

```
namespace my_project
{
    class my_point
    {
    public:
        my_point(int x_, int y_)
            : x(x_), y(y_)
        {}

        // Constructor taking a foreign library type
        my_point(const OtherLibrary::Point& other)
            : x(other.GetX()), y(other.GetY())
        {}

        // Copy-assignment operator taking foreign library type
        my_point& operator=(const OtherLibrary::Point& other)
        {
            x = other.GetX();
            y = other.GetY();
            return *this;
        }

    private:
        int x;
        int y;
    };
}
```

Comment: You could even add `operator 3rdPartyPoint()` if that makes things simpler.

Comment: @arne Thanks, this was the piece of information I was missing. I was not aware of conversion operators, and thought I would have to explicitly convert my type when a function required the 3rd party type.

Comment: @Alex: Beware however that this operator might also be called if you don't expect it. For a Point type that's probably not a problem, but if you have any class type that is convertible to `int`, very interesting things can happen.

Answer (score 1):

When managing data types that are similar in concept from multiple sources (i.e. `Point` classes from various third party libraries), my immediate thought would be to lay down an interface which all data types implement, and to use this interface instead of the concrete implementations.

As others have pointed out, namespaces assist with managing classes with the same name. However, if for some reason you are in a situation where you need a `MyCode::Point` to work directly with a `TheirCode::Point`, you could always implement the appropriate operators to make conversions from each possible. Though, this would not be particularly wise, because as the number of variants for your data type grows, you have to add conversion support to all existing data types.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly, you want to modify the classes already present in a third party library, to suit your needs. In that case, the class from the library is inherited by a class defined in the program. Its like wrapping the class from the library to form a class you need.

The purpose of a library is to utilize the existing code. Its often better to use functions from a library, then to create your own. Yes, Using a library does create dependency. But, thats how softwares are made. Classes inside a library are normally made keeping modularity, loose coupling, high cohesion in mind. Hence they only offer what you need and not more than that. However, you can always extend those classes to add features specific to your project.

Comment: I'd like to disagree with your very last point, that classes provide only what's necessary. For example, the Qt library provides classes that are very, very mighty and often far more so than you need if you want to wrap them. This can really get in the way sometimes, for example on embedded systems.